# How to get the index of filtered item in list using lambda?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda, filter

I have a list of fruits `[{'name': 'apple', 'qty': 233}, {'name': 'orange', 'qty': '441'}]`

When i filter the list for `orange` using lambda, `list(filter(lambda x: x['name']=='orange', fruits))` , i get the right dict but i can not get the index of the dict. Index should be 1 not 0.

How do i get the right index of the filtered item ?

[image]

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: x[1]['name']=='orange', enumerate(fruits)))` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) instead:

```
>>> fruits = [{'name': 'apple', 'qty': 233}, {'name': 'orange', 'qty': '441'}]
>>> [(idx, fruit) for idx, fruit in enumerate(fruits) if fruit['name'] == 'orange']
[(1, {'name': 'orange', 'qty': '441'})]
```

Like @ChrisRands posted in the comments, you could also use `filter` by creating a enumeration object for your `fruits` list:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda fruit: fruit[1]['name'] == 'orange', enumerate(fruits)))
[(1, {'name': 'orange', 'qty': '441'})]
>>>
```

Here are some timings for the two methods:

```
>>> setup = \
      "fruits = [{'name': 'apple', 'qty': 233}, {'name': 'orange', 'qty': '441'}]"
>>> listcomp = \
     "[(idx, fruit) for idx, fruit in enumerate(fruits) if fruit['name'] == 'orange']"
>>> filter_lambda = \
     "list(filter(lambda fruit: fruit[1]['name'] == 'orange', enumerate(fruits)))"
>>> 
>>> timeit(setup=setup, stmt=listcomp)
1.0297133629997006
>>> timeit(setup=setup, stmt=filter_lambda)
1.6447856079998928
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, is it not looping through the list slower than filter lambda? Can the same be achieved through filter lambda?

Comment: Filter filters and doesnt care about indices. You could do it with filter though

Comment: @Steve Well that depends. The `filter` + `lambda` _can_ be slower to to function call overhead and local variable accesses, but I'm not 100% sure. I'll post some timings.

Comment: filter+lambda is a generator though right? So it might be faster if you have a large fruits object and only plan to loop over some of them.